# Intel X4500 vs NVidia 7600 GS

Tags: graphics-card, intel-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card

I've just bought a new motherboard with integrated Intel X4500 graphics (G41 chipset). My old graphics card was an NVidia 7600 GS. I was planning to use the X4500 and not reinstall the NVidia card, assuming performance is comparable or better. I haven't been able to find any benchmarks that compare these two cards though. Can anyone give me an indication of which performs better (just for general Win 7 desktop apps - I'm not playing any 3D games).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question - here's my Windows 7 experience index ratings for the Intel X4500 (using 256Mb of system RAM):

- Graphics:     **4.1**
- 3D Graphics:  **3.5**

And the NVidia 7600 GS (with 256Mb onboard RAM):

- Graphics:     **4.3**
- 3D Graphics:  **4.5**

Answer (score 1):

> (just for general Win 7 desktop apps - I'm not playing any 3D games).

Just for general purposes, both are equal, I doubt you will find much different. For video playback,  again both are equals, with [both](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units#GeForce_7_.287xxx.29_series) [providing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#GMA_X4500) support for Hardware acceleration for MPEG2.